# exit console after starting play framework application

Tags: shell, playframework, playframework-2.3, typesafe-activator

I write a shell script for starting two play framework application.

```
cd /someDirectory

activator "start -Dhttp.port=9001"

cd /anotherDirectory

activator "start -Dhttp.port=9002"
```

after running the shell script, running process sleeps after starting first application (because play framework stay in shell after start command until pressing Ctrl + D)

How can I say to activator release shell after starting?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use any process manager you want :

- screen
- nohup
- upstart
- systemd
- supervisord

BTW, if this is production, you might consider using the start script created when [packaging your application.](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.3.x/Production)

Answer (score 2):

Use `nohup`as follows `nohup ./script &`. It is also useful when starting applications from remote shell.